# How to enhance my skills as a programmer

Tags: programming-languages, books, c

I want to learn Cryptography and so I am interested to master C-programming.

I know the basic concepts of C-programming  like how to use an array,pointers etc.

I want to develop myself so that I can find the different loopholes in the security of different cryptosystems.

Basically I want to work in Attacking of Cryptosystems apart from developing my skills in theory.

Will someone suggest me some goods or a list of books(say) which are just above the beginner's level and which will establish me as a good programmer?

I will be extremely thankful if someone could help.

Comment: Book recommendations are typically off-topic here, as they are subjective, and there might be many different opinions; see our [help/dont-ask] and https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cryptopals challenges

I would really suggest going over the practical exercises on http://cryptopals.com/ which will (hopefully) illustrate practical known weaknesses of existing cryptosystems and ways to attack them.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need books. You need to **write lots of programs**. Since you are interested in cryptography, you should practice writing programs that involve mathematics. A good way to do so is to join [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) and just go down the list. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to investigate [cyberdegrees](http://www.cyberdegrees.org/)

There is a wealth of information on this site including free online courses.